# Laravel Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5, database-schema

I have a table which has ID and also Slug.  I want the Slug to increment as well as ID but when I try this

```
$table->increments('slug')->nullable();
```

I get an error saying there can only be one auto column.  Is there a way around this?  My table structure is below

```
Schema::create('catalog_products', function ($table) {
            $table->engine = 'InnoDB';
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->boolean('is_featured')->nullable();
            $table->string('title')->nullable();
            $table->increments('slug')->nullable();
            $table->text('description')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: no. there is no way we can define two auto column.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want the Slug to increment as well as ID"?

Comment: Any way around how would I create the slug column so it increments?

Comment: As ID increments I want the slug field to also increment

Comment: No, this is a limitation of MySQL's innodb implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have two increments, but you can have a integer slug and everytime you add a row you manually increment your slug.